# How can I do take a substring and length of a string in C# if that string might be a null?

Tags: c#

I have the following strings:

```
var temp = null;
var temp = "";
var temp = "12345678";
var temp = "1234567890";
```

What I need to do is if have a function that will give me the last four digits of the input variable if the input variable is 8 or 10 characters long. Otherwise I need it to return "";

Is there an easy way I can do this in C#. I am just not sure how to deal with null because if I get the length of null then I think that will give me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int length = (temp ?? "").Length;
string subString = "";
if(length == 8 || length == 10)
{
   subString = temp.Substring(length - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use IsNullOrEmpty, As if string is null or Empty then substring is not possible.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && (str.Length == 8 || str.Length == 10)) 
{
    string substr = str.Substring(str.Length-4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string YourFunctionName(string input)
    {
        string rVal = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return rVal;
        if (input.Length == 8 || input.Length == 10)
            rVal = input.Substring(input.Length - 4);
        return rVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would likely write it like this, if writing a function:

```
string GiveMeABetterName (string input) {
    if (input != null
          && (input.Length == 8 || input.Length == 10)) {
        return input.Substring(input.Length - 4);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

As can be seen by all the answers, there is multiple ways to accomplish this.